# How compatible is DirectX with Click Once installer Deployment?

Tags: c#, clickonce, directx

I  added DirectX 9c as a prerequisite in my VS2008 publish.
On running the installer it does not install directx on my m/c.
The exe file only extracts the directx zipped files in the folder and starts my application.

The directX does not get installed on my m/c Why is it so??

Can anybody help..

for long i am struck on this problem...

Thanks....
Waiting for early reply...

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly unknowledgeable about ClickOnce, but isn't its point not to alter the local system at all and rather be sandboxed ?

If that is indeed the case, ClickOnce *can't* install DirectX runtime as part of the system, it would just break the security model.